# Someone who can help me with complement my Java method?

Tags: java

i am completely new to java programming but I am trying hard, hope you can help me to solve this problem. I need to write a java method.
The method should receive the desired number of places as a parameter. The method should check if the section is unoccupied and that the required number of seats and the available number of places matches (see above) the value of the field booked shall be changed only if the check shows that the section is not already booked . The method should return the value true if the section is booked (otherwise false will be returned)
you can see what i came for so far
Thanks in advance!

```
public class Sektion
{
    private String namne;
    private int numberOfPlaces;
    private boolean booked;

    public Sektion(String namne, int numberOfPlaces)
    {
        this.namne = namne;
        this.numberOfPlaces = numberOfPlaces;
        this.booked=false;
    }

    public boolean reserveSektion(int numberOfPlaces)

    {
        boolean completedBookning = false;
        if (booked != true && numberOfPlaces == numberOfPlaces){
            booked=true;
            completedBookning=true;
        }
        return completedBookning;


}
```

Comment: `numberOfPlaces == numberOfPlaces` will always return true since you're basically comparing a variable to itself. Change the first one to `this.numberOfPlaces` to access the variable previously set in the constructor.

Comment: now it works! thanks for your help.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you compare the parameter `numberOfPlaces`  with itself :

```
if (booked != true && numberOfPlaces == numberOfPlaces){
```

So it is like if you had written :

```
if (booked != true){
```

`numberOfPlaces` is also a field of the class but in a method scope, the local variable shadows the field variable with the same name.

So, you should prefix `numberOfPlaces` with `this` to refer to the instance field (or use another name for the parameter):

```
 if (booked != true && this.numberOfPlaces == numberOfPlaces){
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!